# Django template to recognize dropdown choices

Tags: python, django

Each item has I have a dropdown that selects the choice and saves it. Upon reload of the page, I'd like the user to be able to see the choice they have made.

models:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('0', 'All Position'),
    ('1', 'Green'),
    ('2', 'Aqua'),
    ('3', 'Blue'),
    ('4', 'Yellow'),
)

class ColorCoat(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def get_category(self):
        return CATEGORY_CHOICES[int(self.category)][1]
```

what I tried:

```
{% for item in color_items %}
...
    {% if item.category == 1 or 3 %}
        <span>Greenish Blue</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.category == 2 or 4 %}
         <span>Turquoise</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I properly check what the item.category value is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed, use:

```
{% if item.category == '1' or item.category == '3' %}
```

and:

```
{% if item.category == '2' or item.category == '4' %}
```

The expression `item.category == 2 or 4` does not mean what you think it does; it is interpreted as `(item.category == 2) or 4` instead. If `item.category` is indeed `2`, then that expression evaluates to `(True) or 4`, but if `item.category` is `3` that becomes `(False) or 4`, returning `4`, which is considered `True` in a boolean context.

Moreover, you have *strings* in `item.category`, but you were testing against `int` values instead.

Comment: This throws a `TemplateSyntaxError, Could not parse the remainder: '(1,' from '(1,' ` for me.

Comment: @Modelesq: ah, just found the correct [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if), updated.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post. If you could take a look at it that'd be amazing. Your answer seems correct, however its not returning anything.

Comment: @Modelesq: next issue: you use integers but defined strings.